# why does setMaximumFractionDigits not include certain numbers

Tags: java

```
public class Slice {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    double d = 987.123456d;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(4); 
    System.out.println(nf.format(d) + " ");
  }
}
```

Output: `987.1235`

Why does it exclude `4` and output isn't `987.1234`

Changing to `nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);` actually outputs `987.123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you observed was caused by rounding not skipping.